# Spring @ControllerAdvice exception handler returning 404 error instead of view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a controller which can handle all exceptions using springs controller advice annotation.

Below is the class i created for this.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {


private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("Handling Exception!");
    return new ModelAndView(new CustomError("<Error Message>"));
}
}
```

The method defaultErrorHandler is being called when any unhandled exception is thrown, but it seems to return a 404 error to the browser instead of returning the view CustomError. Anyone have an idea why this could be?

The CustomError class is below

```
public class CustomError {

private String errorMessage;

public CustomError(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've used the wrong ModelAndView, the class you've used seems to be `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView` wich has the constcutor ModelAndView(java.lang.Object)

the class `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` which you should have used doesn't have a constructor that accepts Object.

Change the imports and the code accordingly and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think that, there is Runtime exception, which could not be handled by
 `@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)`.

Please post your controller method as well.